# ESP32: LED turns on when deep sleep is activated

Tags: microcontroller, led, esp32

I'm trying to figure out why a LED I connected to GPIO #15 and GND on an [Adafruit's ESP32 board](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-huzzah32-esp32-feather/pinouts) is turning on (but dimmed) when I launch the `deepsleep() mode` via machine.deepsleep() (board running on MicroPython).

The LED pin is instantiated in the code like this: `MY_LED = Pin(15, Pin.OUT)`

The last operation done on the pin is `pin.value(0)`.

Here's a partial circuit diagram:

[image]

Has anyone seen such a thing? Why does it turn on when it's off right before the `machine.deepsleep()` command line?

Comment: Are there any other LEDs connected to other pins ? Do they show same behaviour ?

Comment: Weak pull-up syndrome.

Comment: @Andyaka PULL_DOWN in my case but yes you're right, thanks!

Comment: @AJN none of the 2 other leds I'm using were showing such behavior, no idea why this one was affected in particular.

Comment: You can answer this question yourself so that it will be useful for future readers. I would also recommend that you add two more details t your question. 1.) Last operation done on the pin #15 (HIGH | LOW | Other) just before sleep. 2.) A partial circuit diagram (led and pin #15 alone).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the issue was coming from a *"weak pull-down syndrome"*: I simply changed the pin declaration to `MY_LED = Pin(15, Pin.OUT, Pin.PULL_DOWN)` and the problem went away.